# Windows Phone 8 Panorama SelectionIndex not changing on swiping through items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I have created Panorama control and binded PanoramaItem from ItemSource. Now when i am changing the selected Panoramaitem by swiping over them the Selected index is always set to -1. I dont know what wrong i am doing while implementation. neither selectionchange event is getting fired.
Code:

```
<phone:Panorama Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="Visible"
       x:Name="PnrVwMainNews"
       ItemsSource="{Binding ParnormaItemsData}"
       ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PanoramaContainerItemStyle}">
    <phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Panorma Items Template -->
            <Controls:DynamicContentControl Content="{Binding UsrCntrlDynamic}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```

**PanoramaContainerItemStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="PanoramaContainerItemStyle" TargetType="phone:PanoramaItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PanoramaItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: check whether the SelectionChanged event is working or not.

Comment: no  and its working ! what you mean ?

Comment: I mean when i add SelectionChange event to my phone:Panorama control its not getting fired when i swipe through PanoramaItems..

Comment: Does SelectionChange not getting fired mean anything?

Comment: Please post your `PanoramaContainerItemStyle`

Comment: I have added PanoramaContainerItemStyle please check

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any Selection_Changed event implemented/hooked here.

```
SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged"
```

You should at first define this event on Panorama level.
(Not inside the `PanoramaContainerItemStyle`)

Answer (score 0):

assign null to SelectedItem at last in SelectionChanged event handler, so that new item will get selected every time.